# Identify groups of observations with identical values for sets of variables

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a `data.frame` like this:

```
example.df <- data.frame(grp = rep(1:3, each = 2),
                         attr.a = c(1, 4, 1, 7, 4, 1),
                         attr.b = c(2, 5, 2, 8, 5, 2),
                         attr.c = c(3, 6, 3, 9, 6, 3))

> example.df
  grp attr.a attr.b attr.c
1   1      1      2      3
2   1      4      5      6
3   2      1      2      3
4   2      7      8      9
5   3      4      5      6
6   3      1      2      3
```

I want to identify if any groups (`grp`) contain identical sets of observations for `attr.a`, `attr.b` and `attr.c`. In the example, `grp` 1 & 3 contain identical sets of observations (but, the sets of observations are not ordered in the same way). Also in the example, `grp` 2 contains only one set of observations that are identical to `grp` 1 & 3. It should only be identified if all sets of observations are identical.

It isn't important how the identical `grp`s are identified, as long as it is clear, but could look something like this:

```
  grp attr.a attr.b attr.c ident
1   1      1      2      3     3
2   1      4      5      6     3
3   2      1      2      3     0
4   2      7      8      9     0
5   3      4      5      6     1
6   3      1      2      3     1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that more than two groups have the same set of attr? In this case, what ident should look like?

Comment: @Maël Thanks but in my data that isn't possible. Feel free to offer a solution where `ident` is (e.g.) a list variable, if you have one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may `unite` the 'attr' columns to a single column, grouped by 'grp', `sort` the pasted elements to create a single string, use `match` on the `attr` and grouped by the index, `rev`erse the 'grp' if there are more than one element, do a join with the original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
example.df %>%
   unite(attr, starts_with('attr'), sep="") %>% 
   group_by(grp) %>% 
   summarise(attr = str_c(sort(attr), collapse = "")) %>%
   mutate(new = match(attr, unique(attr))) %>% 
   group_by(new) %>%
   mutate(ident = if(n() == 2) rev(grp) else 0) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   select(-new, -attr) %>%
   left_join(example.df, .)
```

-output

```
   grp attr.a attr.b attr.c ident
1   1      1      2      3     3
2   1      4      5      6     3
3   2      1      2      3     0
4   2      7      8      9     0
5   3      4      5      6     1
6   3      1      2      3     1
```